# Visual Studio 2019 do not break on unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.2) and when running some end to end test that should cause unhandled exceptions the debugger is always breaking even though my exception setting have it turned off:

[image: Exception Setting]

In VS 2019 I'm still getting:

[image: Exception Thrown]

I can click on the Exception settings in that popup window but there are 100's of different exceptions thrown during the tests. I would like to be able to switch this off globally. In previous versions of VS you could turn this off globally in the Exception Settings window.

Comment: This is *unhandled* exception. The settings in the first screenshot are *first-chance* exception. Do you know [the difference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/)?

Comment: Yes I have voted to close as duplicate thanks !